# NMAP won't detect MySQL version

Tags: mysql, linux, nmap, parrot-os

So I am working on a simple HTB and I need to find what MySQL version is running. I know what it is supposed to be I just can not figure out how to get there. The command I run:

```
$sudo nmap 10.129.138.169 -sV -sC -v
```

Response:

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE VERSION
3306/tcp open  mysql?
```

I have tried various versions such as running -p- for all ports or -p3306 to target just that port. Nothing I do will get "MariaDB" instead of "?" (I know this is the answer but want to figure out what I am doing so I can learn for the future. Is there a switch I am forgetting or is ParrotOS different then Kali in some significant way? Because when watching or reading a walkthrough I did it just like them. For example, watching someone do it they ran the same nmap commands as me, got the same response, except below the response also got:

```
mysql-infor:
  Protocol: 10
  Version: 5.5.5-10.3.27-MariaDB-0+deb10u1
  Thread ID: 66
```

etc. Please guide me to where I am going wrong. Not looking for answer hand outs I really would like to learn my mistake. Thank you in advance

Comment: Do not ask for hints instead of answers, as it will only confuse future visitors to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do not want the answer. I will give you a hint. You probably need the `-sC` flag in your command somewhere, like this: `nmap -sC -sV "target ip"`

Comment: Please do not provide partial answers or hints instead of answers. Don't leave future visitors to your answer wondering what the full answer is.